# Dual booting Windows and a linux distro without losing the Windows recovery partition

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, recovery-partition

I have an HP 15-AY009DX Laptop computer that comes with MS Windows 10 Home (64-bit) pre-installed. It has only 6GB RAM and therefore running a linux VM in a productive manner is not an option. Therefore I am thinking of making this computer dual-booting so that I can keep MS Windows and also have linux too. Is there a way of doing this without losing the Windows Recovery Partition? (Is creating a USB recovery stick and keeping it safely in case I get my MS Windows installation corrupted the only option I have to get this HP 15-AY009DX computer dual-bootable with MS Windows and some linux distro?) This computer has a touch screen and if someone could kindly suggest a linux distro that supports touch screen, it is a great favor.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.

Comment: You should be able to make a Recovery USB key from HP Tools on your computer. This will do a proper rebuild including partitions on a brand new drive.

Comment: Most Linux distros support touch screen, and you can test that *without installing it* by running from a Live USB installation disk, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview . This makes *no* change to your HDD and is a safe way to test-drive beforeyou install.